# How to append list item to the return function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
     def tab():
        .......
     return[a,b,c,d]
     [a,b,c,d] = tab()
```

How can I append a list to the defined function. I want to attach Z to the a, b, c and d.
This is the function that I've defined but not sure how to append to the returned list.

```
    reg = ['Z'] 
    df_dict = {} 
    for item in reg:
         df_dict[item].append(a)
```

Comment: `tab().append('Z')`?

Comment: Please show what output you're expecting. The use of a dictionary here seems unnecessary. *tab()* returns a list and you want to append something to that. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. How can I return the separate list function in the output. e.g for a, b, c, d in a dataframe format

Comment: Also, can I attach a word Z in a column format such as reg = ['Z', 'P'] if its for Z then add Z as a column if its for P then add P as a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **change** the value in the function, and not just get the value returned by the function and add to it, your approach should be this:

```
val = [a,b,c,d]

def tab():
    global val 
    return val

reg = ['Z'] 
    for item in reg:
        val.append(item)
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! How can I put the final result in a datafame with reg Z/ item?

Answer (score 0):

Your tab() function return a list and you want to append something to it.

Therefore:

```
def tab():
    return [1,2,3,4]

(list_ := tab()).append('Z')

print(list_)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Z']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. This is exactly I was looking for. Also, is it possible to attach a word Z in a column format such as reg = ['Z', 'P'] if its for Z then add Z as a column if its for P then add P as a column?

Comment: @Josh I'm unfamiliar with the concept of columns in lists

Comment: No problem. Can you suggest how can I display it as a sepearte dataframe for an output?